# How to write a txt file from python GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently trying to make a simple GUI which asks a user his age and name. The names then get stored in a txt file but the GUI is working fine but the names are not getting stored in a txt file. I am getting this error -->

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "c:\Users\Sumit\vs code python\projects\tkinter_course\tut_10.py", line 17, in getvals
> f.write(f"{uservalue.get()}")
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

The code which I am trying to run is as follows -->

```
from tkinter import *
t = (r'C:\Users\Sumit\vs code python\projects\y.txt')
root = Tk()
root.geometry("655x333")

root.title("dance class forum")


user = Label(root, text="Name")
password = Label(root, text="Age")
user.grid() 
password.grid(row=1)
f = open(t, "a")
# Variable classes in tkinter
# BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar
def getvals():
    f.write(f"{uservalue.get()}")
    f.write('\n')
    f.write(f"{passvalue.get()}")
  

uservalue = StringVar()
passvalue = StringVar()
f.close()

userentry = Entry(root, textvariable = uservalue)
passentry = Entry(root, textvariable = passvalue)

userentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
passentry.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(text="Submit", command=getvals).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error tells you everything you need to know.

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

It tried writing to a file, but the file is closed. You are prematurely closing the file before starting the main loop.

```py
f = open(t, "a")
f.close()

# When the button is clicked and getvals is called, the file is already closed
Button(text="Submit", command=getvals).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The simplest solution is to only open the file when you need to write to it.

```py
# No longer needed
# f = open(t, "a")
# f.close()

def getvals():
    with open(t, "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{uservalue.get()}")
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(f"{passvalue.get()}")
```

Using a `with` statement will automatically close the file after it finishes executing everything inside the `with`. Opening a file is a quick operation so it's not necessary to open it ahead of time.

Comment: I did that but now nothing is showing in the txt file, its blank

Comment: @ArnavTripathi Is the file empty, or is it just writing blank values for `uservalue` and `passvalue`? An easy way to check would be to replace `f.write` with `print`

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: @ArnavTripathi There are two potential issues here. 1) The file is not writing correctly and/or 2) `uservalue.get()` and `passvalue.get()` aren't working right. If you use `print` instead of `f.write` you can check the console to make sure the values are OK. If they are, something with writing the file isn't working. If the values are missing, something with `uservalue` and `passvalue` isn't right. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, I tried print and it was working fine

Comment: @ArnavTripathi If you delete the text file and click the button, does it create the text file again? The code for writing looks OK, so I think it might be a problem with the file path.

Comment: yes yes, the problem was that only, the path was wrong. By the way thanks for helping